# How to use Helm to install Kibana with the Logtrail plugin enabled?

Tags: kubernetes, kibana, kubernetes-helm

I'm new to Helm and Kubernetes and cannot figure out how to use `helm install --name kibana --namespace logging stable/kibana` with the Logtrail plugin enabled. I can see there's an option in the [values.yaml file](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/kibana/values.yaml) to enable plugins during installation but I cannot figure out how to set it.

I've tried this without success:

```
helm install --name kibana --namespace logging stable/kibana \
--set plugins.enabled=true,plugins.value=logtrail,0.1.30,https://github.com/sivasamyk/logtrail/releases/download/v0.1.30/logtrail-6.5.4-0.1.30.zip
```

**Update:**

As Ryan suggested, it's best to provide such complex settings via a custom values file. But as it turned out, the above mentioned settings are not the only ones that one would have to provide to get the Logtrail plugin working in Kibana. Some configuration for Logtrail must be set before doing the `helm install`. And here's how to set it. In your custom values file set the following:

```
extraConfigMapMounts:
  - name: logtrail
    configMap: logtrail
    mountPath: /usr/share/kibana/plugins/logtrail/logtrail.json
    subPath: logtrail.json
```

After that the full content of your custom values file should look similar to this:

```
image:
  repository: "docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana-oss"
  tag: "6.5.4"
  pullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"

commandline:
  args: []

env: {}
  # All Kibana configuration options are adjustable via env vars.
  # To adjust a config option to an env var uppercase + replace `.` with `_`
  # Ref: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/settings.html
  #
  # ELASTICSEARCH_URL: http://elasticsearch-client:9200
  # SERVER_PORT: 5601
  # LOGGING_VERBOSE: "true"
  # SERVER_DEFAULTROUTE: "/app/kibana"

files:
  kibana.yml:
    ## Default Kibana configuration from kibana-docker.
    server.name: kibana
    server.host: "0"
    elasticsearch.url: http://elasticsearch:9200

    ## Custom config properties below
    ## Ref: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/settings.html
    # server.port: 5601
    # logging.verbose: "true"
    # server.defaultRoute: "/app/kibana"

deployment:
  annotations: {}

service:
  type: ClusterIP
  externalPort: 443
  internalPort: 5601
  # authProxyPort: 5602 To be used with authProxyEnabled and a proxy extraContainer
  ## External IP addresses of service
  ## Default: nil
  ##
  # externalIPs:
  # - 192.168.0.1
  #
  ## LoadBalancer IP if service.type is LoadBalancer
  ## Default: nil
  ##
  # loadBalancerIP: 10.2.2.2
  annotations: {}
    # Annotation example: setup ssl with aws cert when service.type is LoadBalancer
    # service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:EXAMPLE_CERT
  labels: {}
    ## Label example: show service URL in `kubectl cluster-info`
    # kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
  ## Limit load balancer source ips to list of CIDRs (where available)
  # loadBalancerSourceRanges: []

ingress:
  enabled: false
  # hosts:
    # - kibana.localhost.localdomain
    # - localhost.localdomain/kibana
  # annotations:
  #   kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
  #   kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
  # tls:
    # - secretName: chart-example-tls
    #   hosts:
    #     - chart-example.local

serviceAccount:
  # Specifies whether a service account should be created
  create: false
  # The name of the service account to use.
  # If not set and create is true, a name is generated using the fullname template
  # If set and create is false, the service account must be existing
  name:

livenessProbe:
  enabled: false
  initialDelaySeconds: 30
  timeoutSeconds: 10

readinessProbe:
  enabled: false
  initialDelaySeconds: 30
  timeoutSeconds: 10
  periodSeconds: 10
  successThreshold: 5

# Enable an authproxy. Specify container in extraContainers
authProxyEnabled: false

extraContainers: |
# - name: proxy
#   image: quay.io/gambol99/keycloak-proxy:latest
#   args:
#     - --resource=uri=/*
#     - --discovery-url=https://discovery-url
#     - --client-id=client
#     - --client-secret=secret
#     - --listen=0.0.0.0:5602
#     - --upstream-url=http://127.0.0.1:5601
#   ports:
#     - name: web
#       containerPort: 9090
resources: {}
  # limits:
  #   cpu: 100m
  #   memory: 300Mi
  # requests:
  #   cpu: 100m
  #   memory: 300Mi

priorityClassName: ""

# Affinity for pod assignment
# Ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#affinity-and-anti-affinity
# affinity: {}

# Tolerations for pod assignment
# Ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/
tolerations: []

# Node labels for pod assignment
# Ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/node-selection/
nodeSelector: {}

podAnnotations: {}
replicaCount: 1
revisionHistoryLimit: 3

# To export a dashboard from a running Kibana 6.3.x use:
# curl --user <username>:<password> -XGET https://kibana.yourdomain.com:5601/api/kibana/dashboards/export?dashboard=<some-dashboard-uuid> > my-dashboard.json
# A dashboard is defined by a name and a string with the json payload or the download url
dashboardImport:
  timeout: 60
  xpackauth:
    enabled: false
    username: myuser
    password: mypass
  dashboards: {}
    # k8s: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/monotek/kibana-dashboards/master/k8s-fluentd-elasticsearch.json

# List of plugins to install using initContainer
# NOTE : We notice that lower resource constraints given to the chart + plugins are likely not going to work well.
plugins:
  # set to true to enable plugins installation
  enabled: false
  # set to true to remove all kibana plugins before installation
  reset: false
  # Use <plugin_name,version,url> to add/upgrade plugin
  values: 
    - logtrail,0.1.30,https://github.com/sivasamyk/logtrail/releases/download/v0.1.30/logtrail-6.5.4-0.1.30.zip
    # - elastalert-kibana-plugin,1.0.1,https://github.com/bitsensor/elastalert-kibana-plugin/releases/download/1.0.1/elastalert-kibana-plugin-1.0.1-6.4.2.zip
    # - logtrail,0.1.30,https://github.com/sivasamyk/logtrail/releases/download/v0.1.30/logtrail-6.4.2-0.1.30.zip
    # - other_plugin

persistentVolumeClaim:
  # set to true to use pvc
  enabled: false
  # set to true to use you own pvc
  existingClaim: false
  annotations: {}

  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  size: "5Gi"
  ## If defined, storageClassName: <storageClass>
  ## If set to "-", storageClassName: "", which disables dynamic provisioning
  ## If undefined (the default) or set to null, no storageClassName spec is
  ##   set, choosing the default provisioner.  (gp2 on AWS, standard on
  ##   GKE, AWS & OpenStack)
  ##
  # storageClass: "-"

# default security context
securityContext:
  enabled: false
  allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
  runAsUser: 1000
  fsGroup: 2000

extraConfigMapMounts:
  - name: logtrail
    configMap: logtrail
    mountPath: /usr/share/kibana/plugins/logtrail/logtrail.json
    subPath: logtrail.json
```

And the last thing you should do is add this ConfigMap resource to Kubernetes:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: logtrail
  namespace: logging
data:
  logtrail.json: |
    {
        "version" : 1,
        "index_patterns" : [
        {      
            "es": {
                "default_index": "logstash-*"
            },
            "tail_interval_in_seconds": 10,
            "es_index_time_offset_in_seconds": 0,
            "display_timezone": "local",
            "display_timestamp_format": "MMM DD HH:mm:ss",
            "max_buckets": 500,
            "default_time_range_in_days" : 0,
            "max_hosts": 100,
            "max_events_to_keep_in_viewer": 5000,
            "fields" : {
                "mapping" : {
                    "timestamp" : "@timestamp",
                    "hostname" : "kubernetes.host",
                    "program": "kubernetes.pod_name",
                    "message": "log"
                },
                "message_format": "{{{log}}}"
            },
            "color_mapping" : {
            }
        }]
    }
```

After that you're ready to `helm install` with the values file specified via the `-f` flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting input with `--set` that matches to what the [example in the values file](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/kibana/values.yaml#L148) has is a bit tricky. Following the example we want the values to be:

```
plugins:
  enabled: true
  values:
    - logtrail,0.1.30,https://github.com/sivasamyk/logtrail/releases/download/v0.1.30/logtrail-6.4.2-0.1.30.zip
```

The `plugin.values` here is tricky because it is an array, which means you need to enclose with [`{}`](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/1987). And the relevant entry contains commas, which [have to be escaped with backslash](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/1556#issuecomment-342169418). To get it to match you can use:

`helm install --name kibana --namespace logging stable/kibana --set plugins.enabled=true,plugins.values={"logtrail\,0.1.30\,https://github.com/sivasamyk/logtrail/releases/download/v0.1.30/logtrail-6.5.4-0.1.30.zip"}`

If you add `--dry-run --debug` then you can see what the computed values are for any command you run, including with `--set`, so this can help check the match. This kind of value is easier to set with a [custom values file referenced with -f](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/chart_template_guide/values_files.md#values-files) as it avoids having to work out how the `--set` evaluates to values.

Comment: Thanks Ryan! Also found a [related discussion on Github](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/1987) that led me to the [documentation on the format and limitations of --set](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/using_helm.md#the-format-and-limitations-of---set).